# Straight section of a digital curve

Tags: image-processing, computational-geometry

I have continuous digital curves that are close to a line segment, except maybe at both ends.

How would you delimit the linear section (say remove the red parts) ? The solution needn't be very accurate, but fast.

[image]

Comment: @Piglet: given that we already have the curve, Hough is probably overkill, unless specialized to this case. And Hough doesn't give the endpoints.

Comment: Do you have the points as numeric values in a list, or a CSV or an array?

Comment: That's just a hand-made an illustration. I have a program that generates dozens of such curves in an array.

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm called [Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), which takes a curve described by points (or rather the straight lines between them) and simplifies it to be described by fewer points. The output is an approximation consisting of longer straight lines.

I would walk along your line, extracting the coordinates of each pixel in the right order, then apply Douglas-Peucker. The longest line segment in the output will be the one you need to keep. The trick there is to find the right parameter to the algorithm (the parameter is the maximum distance allowed between the approximation and the original line).

Comment: That's right, Douglas-Peucker is an option. In this case the allowed deviation would be 2 or 3 pixels. As far as I know there's an efficient O(N Log N) version, but a little complex.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I have a trivial implementation in C++ that works really fast. If no simplification is possible, it is O(n^2), but that never happens. According to Wikipedia the expected running time is O(n log n), I never checked. That article has pseudo-code for the algorithm that looks a lot like my C++ implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I have my own implementation. I didn't know about the expected time. I assume we won't be in a bad case here.